# Does fresh start reset combat record?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

Does using the 'Fresh Start' reset your combat record, such as KD, SPM etc? I wouldn't mind the game time,  but not sure if it's worth losing DM if I can't get better stats.

Comment: I deleted my answer for the time being, as you're right... as far as I can see, such as in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/blackops3/comments/3xtbil/a_fresh_start_should_also_reset_your_lobby/), it is still an issue. I thought I had seen a note of this being resolved, but I can't find anything definitive on it. I'll let others that have perhaps tried this recently to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Fresh Start resets your stats to the point it is like you never played a single game of multiplayer.  It resets your kill death and score per minute. The only thing that you do get is a title for it.  I've used fresh start before and after I used it all my stats, challenges and titles were gone besides the one you get for actually using the fresh start.